# Trying to understand how Consistent Hashing works better on database servers

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, foreign-keys, relational-database

Regarding Twitter or Instagram design 
Sharding based on UserID: We can try storing all the data of a user on one server. While storing, we can pass the UserID to our hash function that will map the user to a database server where we will store all of the user’s tweets, favorites, follows, etc. While querying for tweets/follows/favorites of a user, we can ask our hash function where can we find the data of a user and then read it from there. This approach has a couple of issues:

What if a user becomes hot? There could be a lot of queries on the server holding the user. This high load will affect the performance of our service.
Over time some users can end up storing a lot of tweets or having a lot of follows compared to others. Maintaining a uniform distribution of growing user data is quite difficult.
To recover from these situations either we have to repartition/redistribute our data or use 
Sharding based on TweetID: Our hash function will map each TweetID to a random server where we will store that Tweet. To search for tweets, we have to query all servers, and each server will return a set of tweets. A centralized server will aggregate these results to return them to the user. Let’s look into timeline generation example; here are the number of steps our system has to perform to generate a user’s timeline:

Our application (app) server will find all the people the user follows.
App server will send the query to all database servers to find tweets from these people.
Each database server will find the tweets for each user, sort them by recency and return the top tweets.
App server will merge all the results and sort them again to return the top results to the user.
This approach solves the problem of hot users, but, in contrast to sharding by UserID, we have to query all database partitions to find tweets of a user, which can result in higher latencies.

My question is how does consistent hashing help here? Consistent hashing creates a ring and tried to put uniformly distributed servers with virtual replicas. How exactly does consistent hashing help for popular tweetID or hot region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.toptal.com/big-data/consistent-hashing

Consistent hashing is useful when adding and removing servers without rehashing all database but just only the required mapping parts averaging rehashing only to k/n resizing where k is data keys and n is number of servers.

https://medium.com/vimeo-engineering-blog/improving-load-balancing-with-a-new-consistent-hashing-algorithm-9f1bd75709ed